# using rbind two combine two one-column variables

Tags: r, rbind

I am trying to simply use `rbind` for two columns and I use the following (all variables are city names and r considers them as factor)

```
firstcitynames <- rcffull$X1CityName 
secondcitynames <- rcffull$X2CityName
allcitynames <- rbind(firstcitynames, secondcitynames)
allcitynames
```

then when get to `View(allcitynames)` all I get is a bunch of numbers instead of names:

```
[,2276] [,2277] [,2278] [,2279] [,2280] [,2281]
                [,2282] [,2283] [,2284] [,2285] [,2286] [,2287]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help if you provide some sample data for first and second citynames, so we can try to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert factors to characters with `as.character(df$var)`

Here's an illustration

```
a <- factor(letters[1:10])
b <- factor(LETTERS[1:10])
rbind(a,b)
##    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## a    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
## b    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10

rbind(as.character(a), as.character(b))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"  "i"  "j"  
## [2,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `firstcitynames` and `secondcitynames` are of type factors 
you can try this

```
rbind(levels(firstcitynames),levels(secondcitynames))
```

Answer (score 0):

this one also worked:

```
firstcitynames <- as.tibble(rcffull$X1CityName)   
secondcitynames <- as.tibble(rcffull$X2CityName)
allcitynames <- rbind(firstcitynames, secondcitynames)
allcitynames
```